# Ошибка при установке Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

При установке VS2017:

> Не удалось install Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature

Устанавливал MSBuildTools 2015, не помогло. Устанавливал MSBuildTools 2017, вылетает та же ошибка. Как решить проблему?

> Не удалось установить пакет "Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature,version=15.0.27128.1".
>       URL-адрес поиска
>           https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=87
>       Сведения
>           Команда выполнена: "C:\Windows\system32\dism.exe" /online /quiet /norestart /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:"netfx4extended-aspnet45" /All /logPath:"C:\Users\lin\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20180110214954_086_Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature.log"
>           Код возврата: 87
>           Сведения о коде возврата: Путь к файлу не указан.
>       Журнал
>           C:\Users\lin\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20180110214954_086_Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature.log
>       Затронутые рабочие нагрузки
>           ASP.NET и разработка веб-приложений (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.27102.0)
>           Кроссплатформенная разработка .NET Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools,version=15.0.27102.0)
>           Разработка классических приложений .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.27102.0)
>           Хранение и обработка данных (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data,version=15.0.27102.0)
>       Затронутые компоненты
>           ASP.NET и средства веб-разработки (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26606.0)
>           ASP.NET и средства веб-разработки (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web,version=15.0.27005.2)
>           Cloud Explorer (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CloudExplorer,version=15.0.27019.1)
>           Windows Communication Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling,version=15.0.27005.2)
>           Основные инструменты облачных служб Azure (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Средства Azure Data Lake и Stream Analytics (Microsoft.Component.Azure.DataLake.Tools,version=15.0.27005.2)

Comment: антивирусы или фаерволы?

Comment: @KoVadim нет, не они. Без них пробовал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил включением Windows Modules Installer в службах Windows

Comment: да, бывает. Особенно после работы различных "оптимизаторов винды".